# Opencart split test cart module

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I am attempting to create a split-test path for the sales process in Opencart but have been unable to modify the mini-cart's 'View Cart' url.

Here is a [hopefully] clearer explanation of the split path:

```
?route=product/categorya&path=XX
?route=product/producta&product_id=XX
?route=checkout/carta
```

This works up to this point: on `checkout/carta` I have the 'Empty Cart' and 'Continue Shopping' pointing back to the respective links:

```
?route=checkout/carta&empty=1
```

and

```
?route=product/categorya&path=XX
```

I even have the mini-cart's 'Remove' working correctly, but 'View Cart' returns `checkout/cart`, which throughs the rest of the process off.

I have tried the following steps with to no avail:

```
#catalog/controller/module/carta.php
class ContorllerModuleCarta extends Controller {
....
$this->data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/carta');

#catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/module/carta.tpl
<div id="carta">...

#catalog/view/javascript/common.js
/* Ajax Carta */
...
$('#carta').load('index.php?route=module/carta #carta > *');
...
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing but would appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your code is that, you didn't connected it with Opencart. You can do it with 2 ways -
1st - Opencart load cart from common > header.php file using

```
        $this->children = array(
            'module/language',
            'module/currency',
            'module/cart'
        );
```

so your code, carta.php file is not going to load so, it's end of your code. Add your module code here and then load/echo that to header.tpl file and remove $cart else two cart will display.

```
        $this->children = array(
                'module/language',
                'module/currency',
                'module/carta'
            );
```

tpl code

```
       <?php echo $carta; ?>
```

2nd - if you don't want to use default Opencart Cart then just change this line to cart.php file no need to add other code (js code will be needed)

```
        $this->data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/carta');
```

Note - Please use vqmod/ ocmod for code, directly change in core file is evil.

Comment: Thank you! This shed some light on pieces I had missed and am now re-evaluating how best to solve. I recognize that editing core is 'evil' and although I've inherited this and have much to learn about vqmod, I really need two separate paths (and therefore duplicate files from core) in order to accomplish the business directives.